# Spring Boot 2 security - pre-authenticated token - allow healthcheck

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

My Spring Boot Actuator healthCheck is blocked because of a (pre_authenticated) token is missing.

There are many answers available, BUT this is question has interference with pre-authenticated security. As far as I searched, this is **NOT a duplicate**.

How can I allow the health check in a pre-authenticated security environment?

My question is also, do I need more settings (in e.g. the application.properties)?

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider provider = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(new XyzPreAuthenticatedGrantedAuthoritiesUserDetailsService());
        auth.authenticationProvider(provider);
    }

    // Try-1, see below
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.addFilterBefore(xyzTokenRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter(), RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Bean
    public XyzTokenRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter xyzTokenRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        XyzTokenRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter filter = new XyzTokenRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        return filter;
    }
}
```

**My second try was:**

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.addFilterBefore(xyzTokenRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter(), RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.class)
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll();
}
```

Comment: I believe you need to override the `WebSecurity` method and disable all security on the `actuator` apis. Additionally you can use the `EndpointRequest` class to encapsulate your actuator APIs fro

Comment: Sounds good, please show an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the xyz filter is not implemented in the 'perfect' way.

This way will help you get things workin':

1 - use the management port:

```
management.server.port=8081
management.security.enabled=false
management.server.address=127.0.0.1
management.server.ssl.enabled=false
management.endpoints.health.sensitive=false
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
```

2 - configure both ways web and api. Use this beyond the standard parts:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS);
  http.csrf().disable();
  http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/**").authenticated();
  http.addFilterBefore(xyzTokenRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class);
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
  web.ignoring().antMatchers("/actuator/**");
}
```

3 - Inside the Docker container, use the 8081 port for the healthCheck.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add in `.ignoring()` and add `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)`, `@Configuration` at class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer{

 @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
          .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/**");
    }

     @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
          http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(xyzTokenRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter(), RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Alas, still the "Xyz token missing" error exists.

Comment: Hello @Jandroid1 can you please update with a stack trace or full error and can share `xyzTokenRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with your `XyzTokenRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter` implementation. If you wrote that by extending [RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.html), then you must set the property `exceptionIfHeaderMissing` to `false`.

If you didn't extend that Spring Security pre auth core class then you need to show the implementation.